# Saving array of nested attributes with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Project and tasks have a one-to-many relationship, and project `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks`.

In the form, my task objects look like:

```
project[tasks][2][assigned_time]
project[tasks][2][due_time]
```

When the form is submitted I get a hash like:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=",
>   "project"=>{"id"=>"1", "tasks"=>{"1"=>{"assigned_time"=>"09:00",
>   "due_time"=>"17:00"}, "2"=>{"assigned_time"=>"09:00",
>   "due_time"=>"17:00"}}

Then I expect them to be saved by just saving the project object:

```
project = Project.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if project.update_attributes(params[:tasks])
```

But I get:

> WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id   SQL (0.3ms)
>   ROLLBACK Completed in 169ms
>
> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Task(#2188181260) expected, got
>   Array(#2151973780)):

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Projects` model, `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks`.  This will define `@project.tasks_attributes=` if you have a `has_many :tasks` association or `@project.task_attributes=` if you have a `has_one :task` association.

In your form, the following:

```
= form_for @project do |f|
  = f.label :project_attribute
  = f.text_field :project_attribute

  = f.fields_for :tasks do |t|
    = t.label :task_attribute
    = t.text_field :task_attribute
```

In your projects controller, the following:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.tasks.build #=> if has_many
  @project.build_task  #=> if has_one
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you just forget to add task_attributes to attr_accessible list in your Project model:

```
attr_accessible :tasks_attributes, ...
```

And also, note, that, maybe you generating wrong form, because in my current application, form with nested attributes uses task_attributes method, not tasks (like in your hash)

Comment: Actually I had to define task_attributes=. I don't fully understand it, but it's working. I'm curious for the explanation if anyone knows

Comment: Add your Project model to question, please

Comment: attr_accessible was deprecated in Rails 4 in favor of Strong Parameters